# Computer freezes when editing links in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, freeze

I am editing links within my Excel file. These links point to another Excel file on a network drive.

When I do so, often, Excel freezes for a period of time.

Why's that and what can I do to prevent this. Thanks

Comment: And where is your programming question?

Comment: This is more of a SU question. You open that Excel file so that Excel does not have to do it everytime it needs to update its values. Close it when you're done.

Answer (score 0):

Having both excel documents opened while adding it to the links solved the issue for me.

It seems like Excel is going through some kind of loop or bug and spawning a bunch of instances (like 1000+).

More info here: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_winother-mso_2010/the-change-source-operation-in-a-linked-file/7856ad44-9530-4246-b7b0-31d9b53dab22